# Modify a reference numbered group to match against

Tags: regex

I want to match `YYYY-YY` for sequential years.

I'm trying to match where all the second `YY` is the 3rd and 4th characters in `YYYY` with 1 added to it.

So far I've got `{19|20}(\d{2})-(\d{2})`, but not sure how to use `?` with reference to `(1)` or whether I'm going about this the right way and finding out the inevitable "unknown unknowns" (like `YY99`) with this approach?

**Edit:**

Matches: `1999-00`,`2010-11`,`2011-12`,`2029-30`
Does not match: `2010-12`, `2010-09`,`2011-2`,`2011-2012`

Comment: Please give a few more examples of what you are trying to match and what might be close but should not match

Comment: OK, I think I understand the question, but many languages have different restrictions and syntax in regex - what language are you using? Java, PHP .Net, JavaScript?

Comment: How about `1999-00` (eg: `1999-2000`)?

Comment: @CodeJockey I don't know any regex dialect that's capable of handling this (short of listing all possibilities, of course).

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ that could be handled in a procedural part of the code, and I believe it is the part referenced in his question by `"unknown unknowns" (like YY99) with this approach` (my answer notes that regex alone is not sufficient)

Comment: @CodeJockey It'll be for JavaScript and maybe back on the server in C#.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ `nn99-00` should match (I've updated the examples), yeah really didn't want that brute approach, would bloat a HTTP response if it's getting sent to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

1. The hard way is to use backrefs. There needs to be 10 capture buffers per decimal place that will be examined. So, in this case, 20 are needed. There might be other ways to do this in advanced regex engines that do recursion and/or code execution (eval) inside the engine.
2. The easy way, just capture the digits and do post processing.

I'm not sure which engine you are using so below is a sample in Perl to use as an example that illustrates both ways.

```
@samples = qw( 1999-10 1999-00 2010-11 2011-12 2029-30 2010-12 2010-09 2011-2 2011-2012 );

$regex_hard = qr{ 
  ^
   (?:19|20)
   (?:1()|2()|3()|4()|5()|6()|7()|8()|9()|0())
   (?:1()|2()|3()|4()|5()|6()|7()|8()|9()|0())
   -
   (?: \19(?:\1(?:2)|\2(?:3)|\3(?:4)|\4(?:5)|\5(?:6)|\6(?:7)|\7(?:8)|\8(?:9)|\9(?:0)|\10(?:1))
     | (?!\19)\d
   )
   (?:\11(?:2)|\12(?:3)|\13(?:4)|\14(?:5)|\15(?:6)|\16(?:7)|\17(?:8)|\18(?:9)|\19(?:0)|\20(?:1))
  $
}x;

for $date (@samples) {
   print "$date";
   if ($date =~ /$regex_hard/) {
       print "  ~  matched $&";
   }
   print "\n";
}

print "\n----------\n";


$regex_easy = qr{ ^ (?:19|20) (\d\d) - (\d\d) $ }x;

print "\n";
for $date (@samples) {
   print "$date";
   if ($date =~ /$regex_easy/ && $2 == ($1 == 99 ? 0 : $1+1) ) {
       print "  ~  matched $&";
   }
}
```

Output:

```
1999-10
1999-00  ~  matched 1999-00
2010-11  ~  matched 2010-11
2011-12  ~  matched 2011-12
2029-30  ~  matched 2029-30
2010-12
2010-09
2011-2
2011-2012

----------
1999-10
1999-00  ~  matched 1999-00
2010-11  ~  matched 2010-11
2011-12  ~  matched 2011-12
2029-30  ~  matched 2029-30
2010-12
2010-09
2011-2
2011-2012
```

Comment: I am using JavaScript, so when you say `"post processing"` write a function that e.g. checks that the second YY minus the first YY = 1 or has some other logic to confirm the consecutive years.

Comment: @SuperUser - Yes, the postprocessing logic is fairly easy. In Perl, due to the dual nature of variables, its a 1 liner: `if ($date =~ /$regex_easy/ && $2 == ($1 == 99 ? 0 : $1+1) ) { // passed}`

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking what I think you are asking:

> How do I match a range of years in the format `YYYY-YY` when the two-digit year needs to be exactly one year after the four digit year? For instance, I want to match `1991-92` or `2010-11` but not `1990-98` and definitely not `2009-03`.

Then I don't think this is possible with regex (certainly not any popular or well know language or tool). The closest you can come to it is to use something like this:

```
(19|20)(\d\d)-(\d\d)
```

...and then either manually, or with code, verify that the second and third capture groups only have a difference in value of 1 before storing, replacing, or otherwise acting on the match.

**EDIT:**
In reference to your comment, I am not sure whether it would be faster to do a brute force (`1972-73|1973-74|1974-75...`) or to do checking after a potential match to verify the numerical relationship - neither seems particularly efficient, but one seems slightly better (more flexible) and more satisfying: an algorithm to verify post-match. The answer to efficiency probably lies in how many years you want to support.

I'll need a little while to do several unrelated things before I get to this, but you can check back and someone else may have more time than me, or I'll get to it soon. (It is really now more of a [code golf type of thing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) anyways - you may try there)

Comment: Yes, that's an accurate précis of the question. While it's possible to brute force it with `(1990-91|1991-92| ...ad nauseum... |2099-00)`, you're saying it's not possible to verify in the match the increment between `YYYY` and `YY`?

Comment: @StuperUser Not solely with a standard regex engine. No. It would require a specialized engine (that would actually be NON-REGULAR by it's very nature) or procedural code to evaluate any _potential_ match.

Comment: @CodeJockey Sorry for being pedantic here, but no modern regex engine is actually regular.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: define "modern" :D - certainly no POPULAR regex engine today is really regular :D

Comment: @CodeJockey Regex ceased to be regular when they added backreferences... And IIRC that was like 30+ years ago

Answer (score 0):

If you can use AWK then this can be done -

Say you have a file with years delimited by a `,`.

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat years
1999-00,2010-11,2011-12,2029-30,2010-12,2010-09,2011-2,2011-2012
```

With SED, you can have the file as -

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ sed 's/,/\n/g' years
1999-00
2010-11
2011-12
2029-30
2010-12
2010-09
2011-2
2011-2012
```

This output can be piped into AWK for finding successive years -

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ sed 's/,/\n/g' years | 
awk -F"-" '{a=substr($1,3,2); a=a+1; if (a==$2) print; else if (length(a)>2 && substr(a,2,2)==$2) print}'
1999-00
2010-11
2011-12
2029-30
```